# passing static variable value to another function

Tags: java

I have a static variable `totalcontainer` and I am assigning value to it in `main` method.
Now when I call it in another method it gives default value i.e. 0

The value of variable is not updating in second method.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class abc {
    static int totalContainer;
    static ArrayList<Integer> count = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        count.add(2);
        count.add(10);
        count.add(15);
        count.add(6);
        count.add(8);
        totalContainer = count.size();
        System.out.println(totalContainer);
    }

    public static float getCpu() {
        int getcontainer = totalContainer;
        System.out.println("in get cpu     " + getcontainer);
        return getcontainer;
    }
}
```

I am calling method `getCpu` from another class and always getting value 0.

How can I use this variable value in another class?

This is a simple program to demonstrate the problem which i am facing.

Comment: How and when are you calling `getCpu()` ? Is `abc` really the main class of your application ?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the fact that you never invoke `getCpu()`?

Comment: If you're calling `getCpu()` from `main` in another class, then your `main` probably hasn't been run in class `abc` to set `totalContainer`.

Comment: Why is `totalcontainer` and int, but `getcontainer` is a float?

Comment: This is not a [mcve], your `main` method don't call any other class. So this is not the `main` you are using.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic). *-* does that *other class* have its own `main` method?

Comment: Last thing "_This is a simple program to demonstrate the problem which i am facing._" This code print, as expected, `5`. Even if I call `getCpu()`. Please, make sure we can reproduce your problem

Answer (score 0):

If the getCpu() method is called from some other class, main method of class abc is not called.

If you need the count variable updated as in main method, define the implementation in a static block as below.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class abc {
    static int totalContainer;
    static ArrayList<Integer> count = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    static{
        count.add(2);
        count.add(10);
        count.add(15);
        count.add(6);
        count.add(8);
        totalContainer = count.size();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(totalContainer);
    }

    public static float getCpu() {
        float getcontainer = totalContainer;
        System.out.println("in get cpu     " + getcontainer);
        return getcontainer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is in a multi-threaded environment, it is possible that you call getCpu() before totalContainer is initialized. It looks like though as if it is a racing condition.

If you guarantee that the getCpu() is called after the completion of main method, then the value would be correct.

to test this, try this code:

```
    System.out.println(totalContainer);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> getCpu());
```

What you can do since you are using multi-threading:

- First initialize all you want, then start multithreading
- or perform locking, to properly initialize

Comment: That is why it doesn't initialize: due to threading issues beyond your control, the method is called before it should be called. See the edited response